# Handling new line characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, amazon-athena

When I group-by a column, I get the un-expected values from another field.

Here is the sample data:

https://gist.github.com/shantanuo/c8272978575b4a403596ae87f10074c7

And this is how I import it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('s3://todel162/bigd/test.csv', header=None, escapechar='\\')
df.columns=['id', 'client', 'code', 'm_text', 'atpt', 'date']
df.groupby('id')['id'].count()
```

And the output is:

```
id
1234                                1
3456                                1
5432                              118
report it as soon as possible"      1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Basically all the text in 2 double quotes should be part of a single cell. For e.g.

```
"this is line one
and some text on line two"
```

Is there any way to import the data like this correctly (without modifying the source file)?

Comment: I'm almost sure you can't do it without any pre/post processing

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case you can use the param `skipinitialspace`

```
df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', header=None, skipinitialspace=True, escapechar='\\')
df.loc[115:]

        0          1      2  \
115  5432  some_code  case0   
116  5432  some_code  case0   
117  5432  some_code  case0   
118  1234  some_code  case1   
119  3456   new_code  case2   

                                                     3  4               5  
115                                         this is ok  6  20181201031613  
116                                         this is ok  6  20181201031613  
117                                         this is ok  6  20181201031613  
118  welcome to this new bug and \nreport it as soo...  3  20181201031613  
119  this is another newline \nfollowed by a back s...  4  20181201031613
```

If you want to remove the `\n` in the string just `df[3] = df[3].str.replace('\n', '')`